# Android RecyclerView max scroll offset

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, vertical-scrolling

Which `RecyclerView` function returns max Scroll offset?

I need to determine, can i hide footer of `Activity` or not, by `RecyclerView` scroll.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The asked function is recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange();

This function returns true if end of scrolling reached.

```
static private boolean isMaxScrollReached(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    int maxScroll = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange();
    int currentScroll = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset() + recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollExtent();
    return currentScroll >= maxScroll;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Alexander can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952965/recyclerview-horizontal-scrolling-to-left?noredirect=1#comment87861669_49952965